# How do I get the caller widget from a subroutine in Perl/TK?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

in perl Tk I want to ask how to get the calling widget when using the -command option.

I have a dialog widget that is dynamically created by a previously unknown number of entries. There are Entry-widget and next to each a button where one can browse possible (useful) strings for the Entry.

Therefore, if the button next to the 2nd Entry is pressed, the result should be stored in the 2nd Entry and so on.

The code looks as follows.

```
my $count = 0;
my @name = ();
my @val = ();
my @edit = ();
my @button = ();

my $fr = $wind->Frame->pack;

foreach ( @outputs ) {  
    $name[$count] = helper::trim($_);
    $val[$count] = '';

    $fr->Label(-text => $name[$count])->grid(-row => $count, -column => 0, -sticky => 'w');
    $edit[$count] = $fr->Entry(-textvariable => \$val[$count], -width => 30)->grid(-row => $count, -column => 1);
    $button[$count] = $fr->Button(-width => 20, -text => 'Select', 
            -command => sub { &select(\$val[$count], \$edit[$count]); } 
        )->grid(-row => $count, -column => 2);

    $count++;
}
```

However, since &select is called after the complete dialog box was built $count is always on the last value and I don't get the info, which button I have pressed. Lines as

```
-command => sub { &select(\@val, \@edit, $count); }
```

also didn't work.

Is there some way to get the widget that called the sub-routine (so I can store necessary infos somehow in the respective button) or use the actual value (of $count here) in such a call?

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside the callback:

```
my $caller = $Tk::widget;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. However, this solution looks pretty simple but I didn't find this while searching. Can somebody explain the meaning of $Tk::widget?